# "Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference" when trying to access struct pointer

Tags: cython

I want to use a library that gives me a dynamic array. The dynamic array struct has a property `void* _heap_ptr` which gives the start of the array.

After having built the list, I want to access this pointer in cython (to make a copy of the array). But I cannot seem to get the pointer element from the struct.

Here is my pyx:

```
cimport src.clist as l

def main():

    cdef l.ptr_list basic_list
    cdef int i = 42
    basic_list = l.create_list_size(sizeof(i), 100)

    l.list_add_ptr(basic_list, &i)

    cdef int* arr;

    arr = basic_list._heap_ptr

    for i in range(1):
        print(arr[i])
```

This is the error message:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    l.list_add_ptr(basic_list, &i)

    cdef int* arr;

    arr = basic_list._heap_ptr
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

src/test.pyx:14:20: Cannot convert Python object to 'int *'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    l.list_add_ptr(basic_list, &i)

    cdef int* arr;

    arr = basic_list._heap_ptr
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

src/test.pyx:14:20: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
```

And my pxd:

```
cdef extern from "src/list.h":

    ctypedef struct _list:
        void* _heap_ptr

    ctypedef struct ptr_list:
        pass

    ptr_list create_list_size(size_t size, int length)
    list_destroy(ptr_list this_list)
    void* list_at_ptr(ptr_list this_list, int index)
    list_add_ptr(ptr_list this_list, void* value)
```

How can I fix my code? Why is this happening? From my investigations that error message pops up if you have forgotten to declare something as C (ie. use malloc not libc.stdlib.malloc, but I cannot see that anything similar is happening here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

First: `struct ptr_list` has no members and thus no member `_heap_ptr`. It probably should have been

```
ctypedef struct ptr_list:
    void* _heap_ptr
```

Cython's error message is not really helpful here, but as you said it pops up usually when a C-declaration is forgotten.

Second: you need to cast from `void *` to `int *` explicitly:

```
arr = <int*>basic_list._heap_ptr
```